# Selenium: Check i the testcase pass or fail

Tags: selenium, nunit, automated-tests, testcase

Guys First of all I am totally new for Selenium. 
I am having a automation project. In my project, I am creating a screenshot function to take screenshots of my event which I have created for my testcases. Now if my test cases passes then all screenshot should move to Pass folder, else fail folder.

I would like to know how to detect that my test case pass?

I know Nunit detects but I wanted to program it so that I cam place my screenshot as well as log file to pass or fail folder.

Program in C#
Selenium
Nunit to run my test case.

Comment: that is what NUnit is for.  if a step fails, the test fails.  it is very unclear what you are asking

Comment: @sircapsalot I know Nunit detects but I wanted to program it so that I can place my screenshots as well as log file as per pass or fail folder.

Comment: your question doesn't outline your intentions very well.  The only question i see in this post, is `"I would like to know how to detect that my test case pass?"`  please rewrite your question

Comment: @sircapsalot Have you ever done automation scripting?

Comment: I am a contributor to the Selenium project.  yes i have.

Comment: if so Let say you have test case: while runnign the test case, the screenshot which is generated while running your testcase you need to move those to esither Pass or fail. How will you do it?

Comment: For that first you need to figure via code whether test case pass or fail. Based on that you can move your screenshots. So my question is **How will you detect whether test case pass or fail?**

Comment: It depends on what you mean... if you use validations, NUnit will fail and stop the test. What I think you want to do is set the destination folder based on whether the test passed or failed and then copy the screenshot to the destination folder. I don't have any experience with NUnit so you will have to have others help you determine how to detect if NUnit passed or failed... or look it up on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant was this. But there is work around for this. You need to add your code accordingly.

```
 if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.Failure))
    {
        IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("FAILS");
    }
 else if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.Success))
    {
        IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("SUCESS");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check *status property* and compare it with TestStatus enum at teardown method.

**NUnit2**:

> TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status

**NUnit3**:

> TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status